# Why is R throwing a "result would be too long a vector" error when I try to download a TCGA project using TCGAbiolinks?

Tags: r, data-science, bioinformatics

I am trying to download the TCGA-DLBC sequencing data from GDC using Bioconductor's TCGAbiolinks library. I ran the following code

```
query_TCGA <- GDCquery(project = 'TCGA-DLBC',
                       data.category = 'Sequencing Reads',
                       experimental.strategy = 'RNA-Seq',
                       data.type = 'Aligned Reads',
                       data.format = 'bam',
                       workflow.type = 'STAR 2-Pass Transcriptome',
                       barcode = c('TCGA-GR-7351-01A-11R-2213-07')
                       )

getResults(query_TCGA)
```

which worked, however when I ran `GDCdownload(query_TCGA)` it returned:

```
Downloading data for project TCGA-DLBC
GDCdownload will download: 11.806323702 GB
The total size of files is big. We will download files in chunks
At least one of the chunks download was not correct. We will retry
Error in 0:ceiling(nrow(manifest)/step - 1) : 
  result would be too long a vector
```

I was expecting the code to output a file containing the data from GDC on the TCGA-DLBC project, but it ran into an error instead. Is there anything I could do to fix this?

Comment: This sounds like a memory limit problem.

Comment: why are you going for bam file you can download the count file isn;t it?